# accessing another app's elements using C# WinForms app

Tags: c#, winforms, handle

I'd like to be able to do following actions within another application:

- to change Tabs
- to Copy text from within a TextBox
- to click on a Button
- to enter text into a TextBox
- to select DropDownList element

Right now I'm using separate methods such as:

- mouse_event() to change mouse coordinates and click on a button
- another mouse_event(LeftMouseClick followed by the RightMouseClick) to copy a text within a TextBox
- Clipboard.GetText(System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat.Text) to Copy what's inside the clipboard
- SendInput (for each key) - enter the text into a TextBox

Disadvantages of this approach are:

- (not crucial) PC becomes unusable (you can't work while script is running)
- I have to know exact pixels (read - position/coordinates) of EVERY element within an app
- slow execution time (each key has to be typed separately)

I'm looking forward to create an application which can click on a TextBox/Button/List *without the need of having exact coordinates* of these elements.

Is such task possible with C# WinForms? My current approach works but it has it's flaws.
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx). If you plan on scale-ability, read about network communication (for example, the TCP protocol. [TcpListner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx), and [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

There is a complete framework for doing exactly this kind of thing, and it's called the [UI Automation Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348551)

[Here's some examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358520.aspx) on how to use it.
And you can also apply this technique to generic windows's using the [UI Spy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms727247) to determine the automation elements.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).  I have only used it to get text from another application, but it has functions to activate controls by name or to navigate the control tree if there is no name.

You can get text and interact with controls using [AutomationElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.aspx)s that you find using patterns or navigating the control tree.